# How can I set a default editor on Android using Termux?

Tags: android, git, terminal, editor, termux

I am trying to set the default editor, to use with git, on an Android app called termux. However, when I set the value, it says `unable to start editor`. Is there a specific file path I need to provide, or is it just not possible on Android.

I am trying to set the default editor using the command **git config --global core.editor**, and I am trying to set it to an app I have Installed on the device.

Comment: Do realize that `git` inside of **Termux** will need to access the text file as it will use that file for processing. If you install within **Termux** an installable text editor like [vim/emacs/nano](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Text_Editors) that should work. Using an Android app as the editor will require that app to pass back the text file to **Termux** which would require support on both sides.